# java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException when deploying war file in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I'm getting the below exception when deploying through tomcat version 7.0.4. I'm using java 1.7. Seems like it is working with jdk 1.6 properly though.

```
2013-09-26 13:03:58,154 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] -
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initializati
on of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedT
ypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBea
nsOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:947)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.regist
erListeners(AbstractApplicationContext.java:701)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:377)
```

Had googled and found out that it has to do with version conflicts with spring jars.

I'm using the following spring jars.

```
spring-2.5.5 - tried with 2.5.6 also
spring-aop-2.5.6
spring-beans-2.5.6
spring-context-2.5.6
spring-core-2.5.6
spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE - tried with 2.5.6 also
spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE - tried with 2.5.6 also
spring-transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE - tried with 2.5.6 also
spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE - tried with 2.5.6 also

Following are the cxf jars used.

cxf-api-2.6.0
cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.6.0
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.6.0
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.6.0
cxf-rt-core-2.6.0
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.6.0
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.6.0
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.6.0
cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.0
cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.6.0
cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.6.0
```

Tried by replacing  spring-aop-2.5.6, spring-beans-2.5.6,  spring-context-2.5.6
,spring-core-2.5.6 with 3.1.1 also. Didnt help.

Had tried deleting metadata and checking out fresh project, clean build, etc.. but nothing seems to work. Could someone show me the way out of this. Stuck with it for two days.

Comment: Can you put in the contents of configuration file (cxf.xml) ?

Comment: For starters stop mixing spring versions... Either use 2.5.6 or 3.1.1 but don't mix jars... Also the spring.jar already includes everything from the spring-*.jars (and doesn't exist anymore after Spring 3).

Answer (score 2):

I got the same exception at running time. After one day of research, I found my project is using spring 2.5.6. , which is the latest revision while my spring-jdbc is on 3.2.2.RELEASE. I am not able to use spring-jdbc 2.5.6 as I am using some of features that are not available in 2.5.6. The way I solved this problem is simply moving spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar ahead of spring-2.5.6.jar in CLASSPATH. The exception went way. Hope this is helpful to some folks out there.

Answer (score 2):

We had this exact same issue when moving from java 6 -> 7 and it turned out to be the commons-pool version.
Changed it from 
   commons-pool-1.5.7.jar
to
   commons-pool-1.6.jar
and all was fine.